# How to select rows from table 2 based on values in column from table 1 in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table in SQL Teradata:

```
client              | description
--------------------|-----------
John Simon          |arg John Simon
Larry Foe           |Larry Foe por
Judy Gap            |payment 11
```

And I need to find only these clients which has their name (from column "client") + "arg" or "por" in column "descpition" nevermind whether before or after name.
So using above example I need to display only John Simon and Larry Fore, because they have their name in column "description + "arg" or "por" nevermind whether before or after name.

How can I do that?

Comment: use the `LIKE` clause

Comment: could you show whole code based on my table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
where description like '%' || client || '%' and
      (' ' || description || ' ' like '% por %' or
       ' ' || description || ' ' like '% org %'
      )
```

The delimiters in the second part are just to avoid matches for a name like "Portland".

Comment: Great Gordon, but is it possible to manage letter size of "por" and "org" ? because sometimes it could be upper and sometimes not ???

Comment: @gato . . . Use `lower(description)` in the second two comparisons.